# Table labeling and referencing in Rmarkdown

Tags: reference, label, latex, r-markdown, tabular

I'm using markdown to render in PDF format.

I am able to cross-reference plot, but when I build a table in LaTeX, I can't do it somehow. An example:

We plot in Figure `\@ref(fig:plotseries)` the three Index series and their log return series. In Table  `\@ref(tab:summindex_stargazer)` the main characteristics...

while the table has been coded as follow:

```
\begin{table}[!htbp] \centering 
  \caption[Summary statistics for token indexes under study.]{Summary statistics for large cap (L.MWI), medium cap (M.MWI), and small cap (S.MWI) indexes log return series. \label{tab:summindex_stargazer}} 
\footnotesize 
\begin{tabular}{@{\extracolsep{5pt}} cccc} 
\\[-1.8ex]\hline 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
 & L.MWI Returns & M.MWI Returns & S.MWI Returns \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
nobs & $1,524$ & $1,380$ & $1,362$ \\ 
NAs & $0$ & $0$ & $0$ \\ 
Minimum & $-0.351$ & $-0.549$ & $-0.933$ \\ 
Maximum & $0.464$ & $0.699$ & $1.010$ \\ 
1. Quartile & $-0.031$ & $-0.034$ & $-0.052$ \\ 
3. Quartile & $0.036$ & $0.039$ & $0.050$ \\ 
Mean & $0.003$ & $0.004$ & $0.002$ \\ 
Median & $0.002$ & $0.004$ & $-0.003$ \\ 
Sum & $4.144$ & $5.333$ & $2.863$ \\ 
SE Mean & $0.002$ & $0.002$ & $0.004$ \\ 
LCL Mean & $-0.001$ & $0.000$ & $-0.005$ \\ 
UCL Mean & $0.006$ & $0.008$ & $0.009$ \\ 
Variance & $0.004$ & $0.005$ & $0.017$ \\ 
Stdev & $0.066$ & $0.073$ & $0.130$ \\ 
Skewness & $0.236$ & $0.214$ & $1.000$ \\ 
Kurtosis & $4.355$ & $11.602$ & $13.393$ \\ 
\hline \\[-1.8ex] 
\end{tabular} 
\end{table}
```

This is the result.

[image]

Comment: So what is different in terms of the placement of your `\label` within the Figure and the Table?

Comment: Just could not cross reference and make the number appear in the pdf.

Answer (score 0):

Found out the solution. Basically you are not allowed to use “underscore”(_) in table labels.

It was so simple but also so incredibly hard to find out (I personally know many people who’d encountered this error and were not able to solve it). I hope it will help.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to what is written here, underscores are one of 10 special characters in LaTeX.

For underscores to be permitted in table labels they need to be escaped.

This should work:

```
\@ref(tab:summindex\_stargazer)
```

But not this:

```
\@ref(tab:summindex_stargazer)
```

See [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/34580/escape-character-in-latex) for an excellent reference on special characters.